# time execution can show up

Tags: c

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
double multi();

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        multi();
        //printf("Answer (%d)",s);
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    float diff;
    diff = (float) (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time execution :%f", diff);
    getch();
}

double multi()
{
    double a;
    a = 5 * 5;
    return a;
}
```

The execution time appear as 0.000000 what the problem!

would it be cause of the nanoseconeds

Comment: What's the actual granularity of `clock()` on your system? Often it's several milliseconds, and that is too coarse to time just 1000 multiplications. Also, the compiler may have eliminated the loop.

Comment: I never can remember the order these are evaluated so I would use `diff=((float)(end - start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` with an extra set of parentheses. If the divide happens before the cast to float, you will  end up with anything less than 1 showing as zero.

Comment: I think @Daniel's got it, Just kick up your loop to something like `1000000` and you should get a non-0 answer

Comment: @LeeMeador: The expression is ok as it is -- except that I'd use `double` rather than `float`.

Comment: well ,, actually i did not get the idea you are talking about >>i tried double and have the same answer :(

Comment: Also, that's a function that calculates a constant value, which the caller doesn't even care about, so it may optimise to nothing.

Comment: The value returned from clock only changes at a certain rate. Perhaps 16 times per second. If your code takes less than that to run, it will show zero. You might just print out the start and end and clocks per sec values to see if the math is right.

Comment: A few comments, not relevant to your problem. `void main()` is wrong; it should be `int main(void)`; avoid any book that recommends `void main()` for C. `clrscr()` -- why should this program clear the screen?  Declare `multi` as `double multi(void)`; with `()`, the compiler can't diagnose incorrect calls. Your `multi` function is unlikely to perform a multiplication; `5*5` will almost certainly be evaluated at compile time. For most purposes, `double` is preferred to `float`; using `float` loses precision and range with little benefit.

Comment: i tried the double and tried to make 100000 loop no change on the screen!!!

Comment: I wouldn't expect to make any difference. On my system, increasing the count to `1000000000` (1 billion) gives me 2.07 seconds. Computers are *fast*, and you're not doing a floating-point multiplication anyway,.

Answer (score 0):

The man for the [`clock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) function says:

> The clock() function returns an **approximation** of processor time used by the program.

Approximation, so it's not going to be exact, it depends on the granularity of your system. So for starters you can check the granularity of `clock()` on your system with something like:

```
clock_t start =clock(), end;
while(1)
{
    if(start != (end=clock()))
        break;
}
diff=(float)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("best time :%f",diff);
```

Doing this for me, I get 0.001 (which is 1ms), so anything that takes less that 1ms to do I will get back "0" instead. That's what's happening to you, your code is running faster than `clock()`s granularity  and so you're getting back the best approximation  which happens to be "0"

Comment: ooh,,okay my teacher asked to makes loops and compare the time how can i do this??